# Codepen Text Disappears on Safari Browser

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a website which displays text fine on Chrome.

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/RwJeQxX

I've opened it on two Macs with Safari. Text from project-link span comes up white colour. Invisible. Safari seems to count the link as click or activated.

```
<a class="project-link" href="https://www.patreon.com" target="_blank">3,000TWD for a hydroponic farm </a></span>
```

For project-link, I've just used standard link web-styling.

```
.project-link:hover {
  color: #181;
}

.project-link:visited {
  color: #114;
}

.project-link:active {
  color: purple;
}
```

The visited and hover states may be automatically activated by Safari.

Do I need to use vendor prefixes?

Would CSS Reset or Normalize work for cross-browser compatibility?

Comment: Could you put just enough code (mainly the relevant CSS) direct into your question. See if you can make a runnable snippet which shows the problem see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: The codepen itself is runnable on click. It will run fine on Chrome, and show disappearing text on Safari. Live version here: https://codepen.io/Teeke/live/RwJeQxX . I may make a stripped down version later, I know there's extraneous code there.

Comment: There's a couple of points here: don't expect people to wade through a lot of irrelevant code and SO asks that you put relevant code which actually shows the problem direct into your question so that if the external site disappears in future the question is still useful for future readers.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. I'll make a minimal example when I get time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'C' in css is 'cascade' - in other words the order of your declarations, and their specificity matters. You currently have

```
.project-link:hover {
   color: #181;
}

.project-link:visited {
    color: #114;
}

.project-link:active {
    color: purple;
}

a {
    color: #fefefe;
}
```

any tag attribute is more specific than a class tag

Comment: That sounds like the correct answer. I'll accept it. I should put the <a> tag before the specific span tag. Interesting that Chrome and Safari interpret the cascade rules slightly differently. Safari reproduces my buggy CSS exactly as it's written. But Chrome has a kind of error correction, where they will interpret the <a> tag first, and the specific span tags, even if you write it in the wrong order. It seems like Chrome moves rules to the top of the CSS scope, and reorders them according to its own internal rules, but Safari interprets more literally... Might be similar to hoisting in JS.